# Autocomplete do Jquery com Ajax via PHP e Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Tenho um input que é preenchido via autocomplete do Jquery. Simples e eficiente. Mas eu queria fazer com que ao ser selecionado um número desse input (é um número IMEI de celular) ele já procurasse (imagino que seja em Ajax) o aparelho ao qual está atrelado (tenho um banco em MySql pra isso).

Autocomplete:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Modelo que deve aparecer após selecionar o IMEI no input anterior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O autocomplete tá tranquilo. Mas não sei como faço para buscar a informação do Modelo relativo ao IMEI... Na verdade o PHP e o Mysql não tenho dificuldade, apenas não sei de que forma fazer isso (JS, Ajax, etc).

Vou postar parte do código aqui pra facilitar:

```
<h2>Comece escolhendo uma das linhas disponíveis</h2>
                        <div id="form-step-0" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <!-- Include jQuery -->
                                 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
                                 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
                            <script>
                                  $( function() {
                                     var availableTags = [
                                     <?php
                                     $cont = 1;
                                        for ($x = 47; $x <= 49; $x++) {
                                            //Seleciona as linhas em estoque
                                            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sdc_tm_linhas WHERE ddd = '$x' AND usuario LIKE '%ESTOQUE%' ORDER BY ddd ASC");
                                            $r1 = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
                                            if ($r1 == 0) continue;
                                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                                                echo $row['ddd'];
                                                $linha = $row['linha'];
                                                $juntos = $ddd.$linha;
                                                echo ' "'.$juntos.'", ';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        echo ' "" ';
                                     ?>
                                     ];
                                     $( "#linha" ).autocomplete({
                                        source: availableTags
                                     });
                                  } );
                                  </script>
                                <div class="ui-widget">
                                    <label for="linha">Digite a linha com DDD:</label>
                                        <input id="linha" type="search">
                                </div>

                                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               </div>

               <div id="step-2">
                    <label class="control-label"><h2>Dados do aparelho</h2></label>
                    <div id="form-step-1" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="imei">IMEI:</label>
                                    <script>
                                    $( function() {
                                    var availableTags2 = [
                                    <?php
                                    $cont = 1;
                                    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sdc_tm_linhas WHERE linha = 0 AND usuario LIKE '%ESTOQUE%'");
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                                        $imei = $row['imei'];
                                        echo ' "'.$imei.'", ';
                                    }
                                    echo ' "" ';
                                    ?>
                                    ];
                                        $( "#imei" ).autocomplete({
                                            source: availableTags2
                                        });
                                    });
                                    $(document).ready(function(){
                                         $("imei").keyup(function(){
                                              $.get("inserir_ajax.php", function(data, status){
                                                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                                              });
                                         });
                                    });
                                  </script>
                            <input style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 600px;" type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="imei" id="imei" placeholder="IMEI do aparelho" required>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Vc pode fazer com Ajax ou submetendo o formulário (irá recarregar a página).

Comment: Qual plugin de autocomplete está utilizando ? A maioria deles, senão todos, vem com um método de callback, ou seja, ele irá disparar algo depois que você escolher algo no combobox. Dessa forma você poderia chamar outro ajax para pesquisar os dados referentes aquele IMEI

Comment: To usando esse aqui: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Tentei seguir esse exemplo aqui http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp mas fiquei mais perdido ainda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Após o script do autocomplete, coloquei o seguinte:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#imei" ).focus();
    $('#imei').on('change', function (e) {
        var imei = $('#imei').val();
        //$('#modelo').val($('#imei').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "inserir_ajax.php?imei="+imei,
            data: imei,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#modelo").val(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Pode até estar errado ou faltando coisa, mas resolve meu problema! Obrigado a quem se dispôs a dar uma luz!

Answer (score 0):

Falha minha, esqueci de informar que estou usando o SmartWizard em 5 passos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]